# Add a .password file to .p12 file with ubuntu

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, apache-nifi, p12

Using the ./bin/tls-toolkit.sh standalone command, I generate a three files which are :

```
CN=sys_admin_OU=NIFI.p12 
nifi-cert.pem
CN=sys_admin_OU=NIFI.password
```

I am following this tutorial :

```
 https://community.hortonworks.com/content/kbentry/170966/setting-up-a-secure-apache-nifi-registry.html
```

I am blocked in the password entry part in the p12 file.

He uses a Mac so he can use the GUI, on ubuntu I do not know what I have to use exactly. Finally he accesses the keychain access to identify himself.

I do not know how to access the keychain access in my case.

Can you help me please

Answer (score 3):

The P12 needs to be imported into your browser and each browser and OS handles this differently. The article you referenced happens to be using Chrome on a Mac, and in that case Chrome use the MacOS Keychain.

You have not said which browser you are using. If it is Chrome then go into Settings -> Advanced -> Security -> Manage Certificates. On a Mac this will launch the keychain, I would imagine Ubuntu will launch something else.

Comment: I'm using an ubuntu server. And to access to nifi i'm using chrome from my local machine with the UI (windows10). So have I export the p12 file from my ubuntu server and add it to my local chrome ?

Comment: Yes you would add the p12 to your local chrome

Comment: Thank you for your response. I imported the p12 file to my browser when I execute curl https://localhost:18443/nifi-registry  I have this error : curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: Certificate is bad

Comment: Do you think that I have to import nifi-cert.pem generated by ./bin/tls-toolkit.sh standalone command ?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue. I have followed below steps.
Go to the google Chrome then go into Settings -> Advanced -> Security -> Manage Certificates.click on your certificate tab and import CN=sys_admin_OU=NIFI.p12 file from nifi toolkit folder. When prompted, enter CN=sys_admin_OU=NIFI.password file password.

Navigate to the registry UI in your web browser (Chrome used in the following examples):
https://localhost:18443/nifi-registry.

It worked for me.